# how to fork a child process from a child process respectively

Tags: python, linux, process, multiprocessing, fork

I have this code for `fork` a child process from a parent process and i know that :

`os.fork()` creates a copy of the previous Python session and opens it in parallel, and `os.fork()` returns the id of the new process.

I want to fork a child process from a child process respectively, but always it forked from parent process. How it can be done.

```
import os

def child():
    print( 'this is child', os.getpgid())
    os._exit()

def parent():
    while True:
        newpid = os.fork()
        if newpid ==0:
            child()

        else:
            pids = (os.getpid(), newpid)
            print("parent: %d, child: %d\n", pids)
            reply = input("q for quit / c for new fork\n")
            if reply == 'c':
                continue
            else:
                break

parent()
```

the output of above code:

```
parent: %d, child: %d
 (1669, 3685)
q for quit / c for new fork
c
parent: %d, child: %d
 (1669, 3686)
q for quit / c for new fork
c
parent: %d, child: %d
 (1669, 3688)
q for quit / c for new fork
c
parent: %d, child: %d
 (1669, 3689)
q for quit / c for new fork
q
```

Comment: `I want to fork a child process from a child process` So why not try it? Right now your child process only prints a message and exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to    AsTeR and chrk. After i read the answers and some playing around, i ended up with this. I used `os.wait()`.

```
import os

reply = int(input("Enter no of proc:   "))
pid = 0

for i in range(reply):

    if pid == 0:
        pid = os.fork()

if pid != 0:
    os.wait()
    print("PID = {}, PPID = {}".format(os.getpid(), os.getppid()))
```

And the result for `num_process = 3` is:

```
Enter no of proc:   3
PID = 49312, PPID = 49311
PID = 49311, PPID = 49309
PID = 49309, PPID = 20928
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call fork() again from a child, the returned value will be non 0 for the child of first level and 0 for the child of second level (the child of child).

Without any try:

```
def child():
    print( 'this is child', os.getpid())
    if os.fork() == 0:
        print( 'this is a grand child', os.getpid())
    os._exit(0)
```

Output:

```
('parent: %d, child: %d\n', (9663, 9664))
('this is child', 9664)
('this is a grand child', 9665)
```

Comment: Locally it does work. I have edited my answer to fix a typo and display the output. `os.fork()` is 0 in the child, not in the parent process.